# Xpath: robust path for a locator of an element with 1 sibling and one...cousin?

Tags: xpath

This is the code:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <h1>Quorn Stuk­jes</h1>
        <p class="price">
    </a>
    <form>
        <button type="submit">+</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

I want to create a locator that finds the first `<h1>` that has an sibling element `<p>` with an attribute "price". Easy so far. But now I also want that `<h1>` to share its grandparent with a `<button>` class with the attribute type "submit".

What I created was the following:

```
//a/p[@class="price"]/preceding-sibling::p/preceding-sibling::h1
```

I'm wondering if this is the most sensible solution (it does work), or if there is something more elegant and robust.

Comment: Your xpath doesn't seem to mention the button etc?

Comment: Yeah sorry about this one, I'm not sure what i was thinking, i must have pasted the wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

`(//*[form/button[@type = 'submit']]/*[p[@class = 'price']]/h1)[1]` should do (assuming a submit button only makes sense in a form parent element).

Comment: Thats very interesting. I'm only just starting with xpath. Am I correct in understanding that //*[p[@class="price"] means "Any element containing an element p with attribute class=price"?